# Spring boot application not detected by Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

Intellij is not detecting spring boot application created in a different IDE.
The application in discussion is the one starting with the letter "e"

[image]

How can i fix this ? I am using intellij community edition.

Comment: there is no standard `spring-boot-application` which inteliJ can auto detect. If it is a maven project you miss the parent `pom.xml`

Comment: pom.xml is present and similar to the others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, there is no standard spring boot application in IntelliJ.

In the screenshot provided in the question, there is no pom.xml file. If you have that in the project then right-click on it -> Maven -> Add as a maven project.

If this doesn't work, read this https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000023059-IntelliJ-does-not-recognize-workspace-maven-modules for more analysis ways.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a Spring boot application can’t be detected by IntelliJ IDEA!

1. Open the parent pom.xml in IntelliJ IDEA.
2. Right-click there and chose maven, unlike maven.
3. IntelliJ IDEA removes the current maven configuration and rescans again. it offers newly found maven projects to load as notifications. Try them.

Answer (score -1):

Reload your project's maven, it will solve your problem.

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How would that "reload" look like?

Comment: ... and why would it solve the problem?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).